# validate an XML schema against another XML schema which is more restrictive than http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to validate an XML schema (referred to as "schema") against another XML schema (referred to as "schema_of_schema"). The "schema" complies with http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema but has further restrictions.

Background: the "schema" serves as input for a code generator, but the code generator does not understand all possibilities of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema but rather understands only a very restrictive structure of the "schema". Thus, I want to make sure the "schema" complies with this restrictive structure prior to feeding it into the generator.

Example:

schema_for_schema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="xs:schema">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="xs:element" use="required" fixed="data">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="xs:complexType">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="xs:sequence">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="xs:element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="xs:complexType">
                                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                            <xs:element name="xs:attribute">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="xmlns:xs" use="required" fixed="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

a possible "schema" (which should validate against schema_for_schema.xsd): schema_a.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="value"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

another possible "schema" (which should also validate against schema_for_schema.xsd): schema_b.xsd (note the difference to schema_a.xsd: data/a vs. data/b)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="b">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="value"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

an XML file that validates against schema_a.xsd: data_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a value="1"/>
</data>
```

and an XML file that validates against schema_b.xsd: data_b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <b value="2"/>
</data>
```

The XML files data_a.xml/data_b.xml validate correctly against schema_a.xsd/schema_b.xsd. But when I try to validate schema_a.xsd/schema_b.xsd against schema_for_schema.xsd (using xmllint), I get the following error:

```
attribute 'name': 'xs:schema' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:NCName'
```

How can I cope with the colons in the element names of the "schema"s?